# Is it safe to delete duplicity cache folder?

Tags: caching, duplicity, duplicity-backup

I'm using duplicity to the backup web project.
There are three different places that handling by duplicity: storage, DB, and system settings.

I want actually to stop backing up storage and left two others.

So the question is how can I know which cache files related to storage backups and is it safe to delete them (or whole duplicity cache folder), as it takes too much space

UPD:

I've move cache to the new place and change path to cache in configs, after that made few test runs to make that all work fine. Then I've removed an unneeded folder and all the rest backups still work. So it's definitely safe to move/delete cache folder

Answer (score 6, accepted):

generally, yes it should be safe. but as we are talking backups, how about safety first?

1. simply move the folders out of the way,
2. redo the backups you want to continue (observe the "newly" created folder name under cache)[1]
3. do a verify to make sure you can restore everything
4. on success you may delete the old cache folders

done.. ede/duply.net

[1] cache folder name should be a md5 hash of the target url -
 http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~duplicity-team/duplicity/0.8-series/view/head:/duplicity/commandline.py#L112